# Find min,max,average values throw array

Tags: c

I made this code but I can't stop it. This code abou finding min, max, average values.  What should I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_stat_per_test(int score[][3])
{
    int i, k, min, max, sum;
    for (k = 0; k<3; k++){
        min = max = score[0][k];
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
            if (score[i][k]<min) min = score[i][k];
            if (score[i][k]>min) max = score[i][k];
            sum += score[i][k];
        }
        printf("Max=%d\n", max);
        printf("MIn=%d\n", min);
        printf("Average=%f\n", sum / (3.0 * 10));
    }
}

int main(void)

{
    int i, k;
    int score[10][3];
    for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
        for (k = 0; k<3; k++){
            printf("The result is %d student in %d exam: ", i, k);
            scanf("%d", &score[i][k]);
        }
    }
    get_stat_per_test(score);
    return 0;
}
```

After student 5 should stop.

Comment: Why should it stop after student 5?

Comment: @Kotshi OP took input in `score` .

Comment: 'What should I do?' RUN IT UNDER A DEBUGGER OR PRINTF OUT STUFF. You made it, why can you not debug it?  Is your debugger broken?  Does printf() not work for intermediate results?

Comment: @ameyCU Woups, missread.

Comment: Always check return value of `scanf`

Comment: 'if (score[i][k]>min) max = score[i][k];' - copypasta/edit FAIL.